# Case insensitive search with CanCanCan?

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5, cancancan

I'm trying to do a case insensitive search with CanCanCan.
I'm using a custom variable called code as follows:

```
class PromotionsController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource find_by: :code, id_param: :code

  # GET /api/v1/promotions/:code
  def show; end
end
```

Is there a was to make the look up that auto populates @promotion to be case insensitive while still using CanCanCan's query?

Or is this something that needs to be accomplished at a database level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use [`citext`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/citext.html), a case insensitive text type in PostgreSQL.

This lives in an extension so you'll have create that first:

```
CREATE EXTENSION citext;
ALTER TABLE promotions ALTER code TYPE citext;
```

Comment: Thought I might have to do something like that :/ was hoping for something in CanCanCan that would do `@promotion = Promotion.where('lower(code) = ?', params[:code].downcase).first` under the hood. Thanks!